# Add redirection when button is clicked first time then disable it for specific time even after page reload using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement that the user can only click once on checkout button and when user try to order again after some time then he has to wait until button enable again.

**sample picture of shopping cart**

[image: here]

**What I have done so far:**

Until now, I have successfully disabled the button for specific time in js code.

**Check this GIF:** https://gifyu.com/image/c25b

**Things that trying to accomplish**

- I am looking for a way if user checkout first time then on first click on checkout button redirect the user to (thankyou.php) page.
- Lets say, now user is trying to order again after some time, this time button will disable for lets say 10 sec...means user has to wait for 10sec before next checkout...but now I am facing some complications...reffer above GIF

You can see in the GIF file that I am trying to reload the page while button is disabled...you can see button enabled again and countdown pause once I hit reload button...

What I looking is disabled the checkout button even page refresh multiple times and countdown still need to continues in the back... no matter on what webpage user is on...

**I am really stuck at these steps, I would be very thankful if someone guide me...in my above complications.below is my code...**

```js
$.fn.disableFor = function(mins, secs) {
  var i = [],
    play = [];

  $("#check_out_cart").click(function() {

    var selector = $("#check_out_cart"),
      inDex = $(selector).index(),
      prevText = $("#timer").text();
    i[inDex] = 0;

    //Store seconds
    var inSeconds = mins * 60 + secs;

    //Get the previous stored seconds - check local storage
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('time');
    if (retrievedObject) {
      inSeconds = retrievedObject;
    }

    //Disable button
    $(selector).prop('disabled', true);

    play[inDex] = setInterval(function() {
      if (inSeconds > 60) {
        localStorage.setItem('time', inSeconds); //Set time again
        inSeconds = inSeconds - 1;
        var minutes = Math.floor(inSeconds / 60);
        var seconds = inSeconds % 60;
        if (minutes >= 1) {
          if (seconds.toString().length > 1) {
            $('#timer').html("<i class='fas fa-clock' ></i> " + minutes + ":" + seconds + " minutes left");
          } else {
            $('#timer').html("<i class='fas fa-clock' ></i> " + minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds + " minutes left");
          }
        } else {
          $('#timer').html("<i class='fas fa-clock' ></i> " + seconds + " seconds left");
        }
      } else {



        localStorage.setItem('time', inSeconds); //Set time again

        if (inSeconds > 1) {
          inSeconds = inSeconds - 1;
          if (inSeconds.toString().length > 1) {
            $('#timer').html("<i class='fas fa-clock' ></i> " + inSeconds + " seconds left");
          } else {
            $('#timer').html("<i class='fas fa-clock' ></i> " + "0" + inSeconds + " seconds left");
          }

        } else {
          localStorage.removeItem('time');
          $(selector).prop("disabled", false);
          clearInterval(play[inDex]);
          $('#timer').html(prevText);

        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
};

$(function() {
  $("#check_out_cart").disableFor(0, 10); // First parameter stands for minutes and the second for the seconds.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="popover_content_wrapper">
  <span id="cart_details"></span>

  <div align="right">

    <button class="btn btn-success" id="check_out_cart">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> 
                Checkout
              </button>

    <button class="btn btn-default" id="clear_cart">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove all</button>
  </div>

  <div align="right">
    <small id="timer">Ready to checkout.</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am writing up an answer for you and will post it shortly.

Comment: Thankyou @AlwaysHelping...I am actually a php developer and newbie in jQuery

Comment: All good. i have answered your previous question where i added localstorage functionality i know what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: You can get some  reference from here: https://vimeo.com/user121031613/review/445800825/a17e27d33d  you can see after multiple refresh button automatically enable again

Comment: I know exactly what you are trying to do. I have posted a working answer below which will cover all your points in the question.

Comment: Can you specify if all is good now ? I am not sure why you deleted the comments. have you followed all the explanation below ?

Comment: when we hit the button first time...the timer started...thats what i want to prevent....I want if user hit first time checkout button he will redirect to thankyou.php....when again he try to checkout next time, this time he will automatically redirect to thankyou page after time hit to 0...and we already done this part.

Comment: So you want the user to wait for the `timer` only the first time (means 1 time only) and never again ?

Comment: NO, exact opposite... I want user not to wait first time...then always Wait for timer...

Comment: scenario, user added item to the cart and this is the first time he added something... once he hit the checkout button first time..he do not have to wait...just directly redirect to the thankyou page....now second time when he again want to checkout with diffrent items in his cart, now I want to show him a timer...of 10sec... actually I want to add some gap between his first and second checkout or rest of...with 10sec..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219454/discussion-between-alwayshelping-and-codelone).

Comment: Join the discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working solution for you (Tested and its working in my browser). You need to add `localStorage` for each checkout you will perform and in the `localStorage` you are already saving the `seconds`

As soon as the `timer` hits `zero` the user will be redirected to `thankyou.php` and in that page you will remove the `localStorage` which will setted up for this checkout.

If you can come back to `checkout` again and you press `checkout` button the timer starts at 10 seconds and if you refresh within that time and you press checkout again the timer will start from the remaining and once that time finished we will redirect user to `thankyou.php` page where we will remove `localStorage` again.

This process will **go over and over again** without any issue no matter how many checkout you complete.

**Checkout HTML**

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="popover_content_wrapper">
  <span id="cart_details"></span>

  <div align="right">

    <button class="btn btn-success" id="check_out_cart">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> 
                Checkout
              </button>

    <button class="btn btn-default" id="clear_cart">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove all</button>
  </div>

  <div align="right">
    <small id="timer">Ready to checkout.</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

As you can see here i have added `window.location.href` which will used for redirection and i am redirecting it `thankyou.php` page once the `timer` hits **0**

```
<script>

//Click event for disabled first time
$("#check_out_cart").click(function() {
  //Set local storage
  var checkFirst = localStorage.hasOwnProperty('firstTime'); 
  if (!checkFirst) {
    localStorage.setItem('firstTime', true); //Set first time entry
  }
  //Disable for 10 seconds if its not a first time.
  disableFor(0, 10)
});

//Disable checkout function
function disableFor(mins = null, secs = null) {

  var checkRevist = localStorage.getItem('firstTime'); 
  if (checkRevist == 'true') {
    window.location.href = 'thankyou.php'; //Redirect to thank you page.
    //Set it to false
    localStorage.setItem('firstTime', false); //Set first time entry
  } else {
    var i = [],
      play = [];
    var selector = $("#check_out_cart"),
      inDex = $(selector).index(),
      prevText = $("#timer").text();
    i[inDex] = 0;

  //Store seconds
  var inSeconds = mins * 60 + secs;

  //Get the previous stored seconds - check local storage
  var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('time');
  if (retrievedObject) {
    inSeconds = retrievedObject;
  }

  //Disable button
  $(selector).prop('disabled', true);

  play[inDex] = setInterval(function() {
    if (inSeconds > 60) {
      localStorage.setItem('time', inSeconds); //Set time again
      inSeconds = inSeconds - 1;
      var minutes = Math.floor(inSeconds / 60);
      var seconds = inSeconds % 60;
      if (minutes >= 1) {
        if (seconds.toString().length > 1) {
          $('#timer').html("<i class='fas fa-clock' ></i> " + minutes + ":" + seconds + " minutes left");
        } else {
          $('#timer').html("<i class='fas fa-clock' ></i> " + minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds + " minutes left");
        }
      } else {
        $('#timer').html("<i class='fas fa-clock' ></i> " + seconds + " seconds left");
      }
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('time', inSeconds); //Set time again
      if (inSeconds > 1) {
        inSeconds = inSeconds - 1;
        if (inSeconds.toString().length > 1) {
          $('#timer').html("<i class='fas fa-clock' ></i> " + inSeconds + " seconds left");
        } else {
          $('#timer').html("<i class='fas fa-clock' ></i> " + "0" + inSeconds + " seconds left");
        }
      } else {
        window.location.href = 'thankyou.php'; //Redirect to thank you page.
        $(selector).prop("disabled", false);
        clearInterval(play[inDex]);
        $('#timer').html(prevText);
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
  }
}

//Checking on page reload if there is a time left - time > 0
$(function() {
  //Get the previous stored seconds - check local storage
  var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('time');
  if (retrievedObject) {
    //Check previous timer - if page reloaded.
    disableFor()
  }
});
</script>
```

**thankyou.php**

This will your thank you page php. Here you will `remove` the `localStorage` of the time for **each** `checkout`.

```
<?php

?>

<div id="popover_content_wrapper">
 <h1>Thanks you!!!!</h1>
</div>

<script>

//Remove storage
localStorage.removeItem('time');

</script>
```

Comment: @codelone so you want keep the button `disabled` if timer is more 0 and user hits reload ?